# How to vertically aligned to middle with bootstrap?

Tags: html, css

I am  trying to create a layout to make two up and down arrows stacks on top of another. Currently the arrows are aligned horizontally. I am not sure how to make it stacked and vertically aligned to middle along with the `Title` text. How do I do this?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8">Title</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <a href="">                                 
            <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-up"></div>
        </a>
        <a href="">
            <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
    padding:20px;
    background-color:green;
    color:white;
}

a div {
    color:white;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/371yuk1r/2/

Thanks a lot!

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: There are some helper classes in Bootstrap, which you can use for your code. Check out these link please: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-center

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution without using class from `bootstrap` is to add `display: table-row;` to `a` element like:

**html**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8">Title</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <a href="" class="arrowVert">                                 
            <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-up"></div>
        </a>
        <a href="">
            <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.arrowVert {
    display: table-row;
}
```

[**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ocjfg81e/)

Answer (score 1):

There are some helper classes in Bootstrap, which you can use for your code.
Check out these link please: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-center

Comment: This should be under comments.

Comment: I'm not able to comment, vote me up so I can put it into a comment.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8">Title</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <a href="#">                                 
            <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-up"></div>
        </a>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <a href="#">
            <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

You want like this ?

Comment: Also add a line-height for aligning the Title with the arrows vertically.